# Can motherboard support 1TB hard disk

Tags: linux

I purchased a new Seagate hard disk. When I installed in my linux machine, while booting it 
says

> fsck.ext3 file system not found enter
>   the root password.

Do any one have a solution for 
this problem?

Comment: this is a programming Q&A site, try asking this question on serverfault.com or superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

If its a sata drive, chances are yes, almost certainly. Some motherboards have a size limit for pata drives, particularly old ones. Of course there's a whole load of useful information you've left out.

1. Does the drive show up in bios?
   (if so, yes)
2. Have you formatted the drive?
   (mkfs of some sort, or one of the parted varients)
3. is this a fresh install to the drive, or an attempt to add space to an existing system?

also [this might be of use](http://www.fonerbooks.com/ide_hd.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the hard drive has not been partitioned or formated.

Have you checked the drive in the fdisk tool?